# delimiter issue in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

ok i know this something simple but where do i change this so the url doesnt get chopped off

this is the line in my .bat file:

```
FOR /F "eol=# tokens=2 delims==" %%m IN ('find "URL" ^<settings.ini') DO SET address=%%m
```

the issue isin the settings.ini it looks like this:

```
#URL of Video
URL=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCIfNiiYU8o
```

So what it is doing is only returning the following

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
```

i need this to still work if the URL doesn't have a "=" in it. so that is another worry. i am sure there is a way to fix the delim to leave the second "=" sign alone

Comment: you want the whole URL?

Comment: yes the whole url or everything after URL=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR /F "eol=# tokens=1* delims==" %%m IN ('find "URL" settings.ini') DO SET "address=%%n"
```

?

OR another way:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "eol=# tokens=* delims=" %%m IN ('find "URL" settings.ini') DO SET "%%m"

set address=%URL%
echo %address%
```

Comment: that did it...  i tried doing it in two line using the v= but that didnt work, but this did thank you.
i am assuming the * allowed for both "=" to be allowed and "m" was first "=" and "n" after "=" second and so on

Comment: `*` means don't parse nothing after the first token and assign it to the next.

Comment: wait i was wrong it has cut out the "v=" from the line